# How to amend CiviCRM Event URL

Tags: civievent, urls

I have CiviCRM installed on Drupal. I am using CiviEvents, when i click a link to view the event the url is displayed as:

info%3Fid%3D8%26reset%3D1

Is there anyway i can clean this up? Would prefer if i can have it like:

info/id/8 or info?reset=1&id=8

I have installed the module "Query Parameters To URL" for Drupal and have tried setting Path Aliases but no luck...

Any Ideas?

Thanks,

Moe

Comment: Can you provide some more information about from where you clicked event url link? From civicrm manage event page or some where else?

Comment: @PradeepNayak - Hi Mate thanks for replying from a drupal view using the field "CiviCRM Link".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a known [issue](https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-21716) for a quiet a long time and has been no progress on it. Alternate way of doing this would be to use global text (or use the event title field) and rewrite the output as a link and generate the link as civicrm/event/info?reset=1&id=[id].

HTH

Pradeep

Comment: This worked, thanks!